# What about the syntax of this regular expression is Visual Studio warning about?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

```
var STRIP_PHN_REG_EX = /[\x\X\(\)\.\-\s\',]/g;
```

Visual Studio gives the following not-very-detailed warning: "Syntax error in regular expression"

However, the regular expression runs fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think you need quite so many backslashes ... ".", "(", ")", those are fine in `[ ... ]` subexpressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\x` and `\X` are not valid here. `\x` can be used with two hexadecimal digits to identify a specific character — for example, `\x09` means the tab character (`\t`) — but you're not using it that way here; and `\X` has *no* uses in JavaScript regexes.

But since I can't tell what you *want* the regex to do, I can't tell you how to fix it. Maybe you just meant

```
var STRIP_PHN_REG_EX = /[xX().\-\s',]/g;
```

? (That matches any whitespace character, as well as any of `x`, `X`, `(`, `)`, `.`, `-`, `'`, `,`.)

---

**Edited to add:** Or maybe by `\x` and `\X` you meant "lowercase hex digit" and "uppercase hex digit", respectively? There's no special syntax for that in JavaScript, but you can write:

```
var STRIP_PHN_REG_EX = /[0-9a-fA-F().\-\s',]/g;
```